# Draggable canvas with objects

Tags: jquery, canvas

I'm having a problem with my canvas map. What I want is that if i drag my canvas the div will stay on the same place inside the canvas. I want this because I have objects on the canvas. And what I want is that when I hover over the objects the cursor changes to a pointer. 
What I thought of:

```
jQuery( function(){
var settings    = {
    canvasElement:  document.getElementById('map'),
    background:     'Canvas link',
    objects:

objects().addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);


function mouseOver(){
    objects.style.cursor = "pointer";
}
```

But it isn't working. It says referenceerror objects is not defined.

Comment: Any shape (==Path) drawn on canvas is not remembered and therefore cannot be hover-tested. Learn about Path2D which is an object that remembers  path-shapes so those shapes can be hover-tested

Comment: Do you have some tips on where i can learn about path2D?

Comment: Search html5 canvas path2d. Then search html5 canvas drag.